# Zend Unset Action helper from controller action

Tags: php, zend-framework, controller, helper

Zend framework talk.I'm initializing in my bootstrap class My_Action_Helper_Custom (extending Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Abstract) to make it available to all of my controllers.

**Could I just disable it for a specific action where I dont need it?**

thanks

Luca

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you referring to disabling the `preDispatch()` or `postDispatch()` hooks for a particular controller action?

If so, I'd add some form of blacklist property to the helper, for example

```
/**
 * @var array
 */
private $blacklistActions = array();

public function addBlacklistAction($action)
{
    // store actions in string form
    // eg, module.controller.action
    $this->blacklistActions[] = $action;
}

public function preDispatch()
{
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $action = sprintf('%s.%s.%s',
            $request->getModuleName(),
            $request->getControllerName(),
            $request->getActionName());
    if (in_array($action, $this->blacklistActions)) {
        return;
    }

    // the rest
}
```

Comment: should I call the addblacklistAction from the controller??

Comment: @luca I'd do it from the Bootstrap before adding it to the helper broker